# Intellij IDEA: I want to add Web-Inf/Classes to subversion

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, web-inf

I want to add the WEB-INF/classes to subversion using Intellij IDEA. It may not be the ideal workflow, but it is the one I must use because of work. Tortoise SVN detects the .class changes, but IDEA only gives me the option to commit .java files.

Any idea why tortoise is seeing the changes but IDEA is not?

Answer (score 0):

The folder might be included in the special `svn:ignore` property.  From the command line run:

```
cd /path/to/PROJECT/WEB-INF
svn proplist .
svn propget "svn:ignore" .
```

This will tell you if they are in fact being ignored, should probably do the same test for the classes directory and it's sub-directories.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The .class files (and folders) are not displayed as "ignored". It's very strange...

Comment: Makes me wonder if IntelliJ has it's own setting for ignoring certain file patterns from version control.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @vinnyjames 's answer, you can also check that the file is not ignored by IntelliJ itself in `Settings > Version Control > Ignored Files`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the ignored files this items are not displayed... Very strange...